# VHDL - Designing a simple first order IIR filter

Tags: filter, vhdl, xilinx, digital

I'm designing a simple first order IIR filter for my Spartan-6 but I'm struggling with bus widths and coefficient quantization.

The input data is 16-bits wide comes from integrated ADCs and the quantization noise is the main noise contribution to the front end noise.

The input signal is filtered at roughly 300kHz and I want to implement a first order IIR filter at tunable frequencies of 1Hz, 10Hz, 100Hz, 1kHz, 10kHz: let's focus on the 1Hz filtering. In theory I should be able to gain N = log2(300k) = 18 bits of resolution.

I've computed the filter coefficients:

Gain: 3.1416e-6

Numerator: [1 1]

Denominator: [1 -0.999993717]

How do I deal with fractional coefficients? I was thinking to multiply the coefficients times 2^N and then cut N LSBs, choosing N to have a reasonable approximation of the coefficients.

Let's say I use this structure:
[image: First order IIR filter]

What should be the bus width of **z-1 register and the y output** using this multiplication method?

---

Thanks to Jonathan for the help, I still need to understand some things so let's make this practical: first of all, which structure do you think is the best one for FPGA implementation?

[image: Possible structures]

In any case let's say I multiply:

```
b = 3.1416e-6 * 2^36   --> 110100101101001111
a = 0.999993716 * 2^17 --> 011111111111111111
```

Now what? :D

Answer (score 1):

You deal with fractional coefficient by multiplying them by 2**N, just like you thought. This gives you a fixed point representation with N binary decimal places. You have to take care of keeping track of the fractional part width.

For example, if you multipy an input (16 bits integer, 0 bits fractional) with a coefficient (1 bit integer, N bits fractional), you would end up with a 17+N bits number with 17 bits integer, N bits fractional. When you add number, make sure to align the integer parts together...

For how large N should be, it's up to you! Matlab's fdatool can help you visualize the impact of bit quantization on the filter. Matlab/Simulink is the best tool to analyze impact of quantifiation wherever it happens in your filter IMO.

In a FPGA though, I would put N as large as the multiplier allow me. For example, if you use 18x18 multipliers, just use 18 bits (must be signed) for the coefficient. If it's not enough, think about prescaling your input, larger multiplier input will cost a lot more, but maybe you have plenty of multiplier to spare.

Also take note that when truncating a fixed-point number, you can *round* to reduce your noise. Simply add 0.5 before truncation, which can usually be done somewhere on your pipeline with minimal cost.

### Update

Xilinx has a nice [whitepaper on IIR filtering](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/white_papers/wp330.pdf) that may help you out better than I.

Otherwise, I just realized that your filtering requirements are quite drastic (1Hz cutoff out of 300kHz). I doubt you can achieve stability with 18 bits multipliers. You may want to look for a different design, one that decimate the input to a lower frequency as a first stage operation, for example.

If you need to keep your current requirements intact, you will have to use larger multipliers and adders.

Comment: So the preliminar process is to compute the fixed point expression of the coefficients: I get the coefficient, multiply by 2^N, round it, convert it to binary and shift it back by N bits. This way I should end up with a number with X bit integer (depending on the original coefficient) and N bit fractional. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes! I find it really hard to explain that... You transform a real to a fixed point with N fractional bits by multiplying by 2**N. It is important to keep track of the number representation. What works best for me is to do theoretical calculations with the Real values multiplied by 2^N, you will realize, if done properly, it doesn't change the result, only scales the answer by another factor 2^M. When you implement the design, you scale by 2^N then floor the value, the flooring operation introducing quantification noise.

Comment: Did you mean 2^N and not 2^M? I think I'm getting a grasp of it, my problem is the gain coefficient is very small and 2^17 is not enough to make it greater than 1. Does this mean I have to use two multipliers for this coefficient?

Comment: I used 2^M since the output may have a different scaling. If your coefficient is smaller than 1, just scale by a greater N, use the largest N that makes the result 18 significant bits. Just remember all numbers you add must have the same scaling, which can be arranged by shifting. When you multiply a 2^N and 2^M scaled numbers, the answer is scaled by 2^(N+M).

Comment: I think you lost me, I've added my doubts on the original question! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Regarding your small gain coefficient, this is how you do it in case it was unclear: 3.1416e-6 * 2^36 = 215889.
215889 has exactly 18 significant bits. Feed this to your multiplier.

You just remember that your decimal point is now 36 binary places to the left. So, some time later you just divide your result by 2^36 (Right shift 36 bits) if you want the integer result.

By the way, why is your gain pi*10^-6?? :-)

Comment: @TimmyBrolin I don't know why it turns out to be pi, but I need to multiply by that factor to make the gain of the filter 1

Comment: @JonathanDrolet Thanks for the reference, I have another question: can I resize the numbers in terms of bits (for example truncating some fractional bits) in any point of the filter? Because without doing it I can't match the bus widths in the feedback loop: the needed bits just increase iteratively. More on this, let's say I want 16bits integer 16bits fractional for the output, can I send back in the loop this resized number or should if close the feedback before resizing?

Comment: You can, and must. Doing so introduce noise, which can make your filter unstable. Since your coefficient are almost 20 bits apart, your dynamic range is very high and you will have to keep a lot of bits. Matlab has tools to study filter stability depending of where you truncate and how many bits you keep in the filter.

Comment: Any chance you can tweak the filter a bit so that you get more reasonable coefficients?